# K8s pod created by statefulset is stuck in pending state, waiting for pvc bound

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, kubernetes-statefulset

I created a statefulset with volumeClaimTemplates which bounds to pre-created PV.

The problem is the pod created by statefulset is stuck in pending state, waiting for PVC bound.

But the PVC is already bound with PV. So When I delete the pod, the pod is successfully mounted.

I am using an EKS fargate cluster and I think it might be an issue with EKS. How can I solve this problem without manually deleting the pending pod?

pod event log

> Events:   Type     Reason            Age        From
> Message   ----     ------            ----       ----
> -------   Warning  FailedScheduling    fargate-scheduler  Pod not supported on Fargate: volumes not supported: efs-vol not supported
> because: PVC efs-vol-collector-statefulset-0 not bound